# PHP - eregi deprecated in contact form

Tags: php

I have a site with a contact for which has..

`if (email_is_valid($youremail) && !eregi("\r",$youremail) && !eregi("\n",$youremail) && $yourname != "" && $yourmessage != "" && substr(md5($user_answer),5,10) === $answer)`

The site was upgraded to php 5.3 and now users received a deprecated warning....

I have no idea and have tried to change with pregmatch directly but fail...miserably

Please help...

Comment: The regular expressions being used are kind of pointless if the email_is_valid function is correctly validating the email address.

Comment: You should use the Validation built into PHP. See the example here: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php - No regexes needed at all

Comment: Thanks so redeisgn the entire contact form. That's cool but I don't know php.....

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the suggested ways of converting `eregi` to non-deprecated PHP functions: [Differences from POSIX regex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php).

Comment: Thanks, problem is I am not a coder and have tried a direct replacement but it fails, it is a live site so hessitant to keep funbling my way..